# accessing bag values in record in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a record as detailed below in pig
(e5a22039edba467cb738f3794de577b6,{(Fortnite),(OT4),(Main),(New User),(Manual)},bbeeabd3d3ed42c1a7e65838fabb16e3)

I would like to access the data in {(Fortnite),(OT4),(Main),(New User),(Manual)} along the other values in the record. Please suggest how I can do this

Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us a lot of information, but I guess you can use $X to access your fields. " {(Fortnite),(OT4),(Main),(New User),(Manual)} " is bag in the second position so you can access it with $1 ($0 is the first element).

A sample of code to access to "Fortnite" would be :

```
A = LOAD 'file.txt' USING PigLoader(',') AS [.......];
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $1.$0 as Fortnite;
```

Is that ok ?